# Copy a macro in an Excel file in "ThisWorkbook" from MATLAB

Tags: vba, excel, matlab

I wrote a macro in a text file (`Macro.txt`) and I have an Excel file (`Result.xlsm`). I need to copy the macro in Excel file in "ThisWorkbook" from MATLAB (picture below). I tried the following code, using the `import` function. But it write the macro as a module. I am wondering if there is any way to write the macro in "ThisWorkbook"?

[[image: The place that I need to copy the macro code]]

```matlab
ResultFileName = [pwd() filesep 'Result.xlsm'];
MacroFileName = [pwd() filesep 'Macro.txt'];

% Import the excel file
Excel= actxserver('Excel.Application');
wb=Excel.Workbooks.Open(ResultFileName);
Excel.visible = 1;

% Add the macro to the excel file
import(wb.VBProject.VBComponents,MacroFileName);

% Save
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 0; %Avoid overwrite warning
SaveAs(wb,ResultFileName);
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 1;

% Close Excel
Quit(Excel);
delete(Excel);
```

Comment: Excellent use of `filesep`! I don't see that often enough. :) Note you can also use `fullfile(pwd,'Result.xlsm')`.

Comment: The other solution would be to run another macro from MATLAB to write the required macro in 'ThisWorkbook'.

Comment: While macros *can* exist in document modules `ThisWorkbook`, `Sheet1`, etc., they normally *belong* in a standard/procedural module. If you *really* want to write to `ThisWorkbook`, you'll need to get the `VBComponent` for it, and invoke the VBIDE API method to write to that module - something like `wbf.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString(content)`; `CodeModule.AddFromFile(path)` might be worth trying too. Now as you can see, `"ThisWorkbook"` is localized, so prepare for headaches. Much simpler to just have macros in a dedicated standard module.

Comment: There's some typos in your code, `xls` should be `Excel` in `xls.visible` and `xls.Application`, since that's how you declared the Excel object. And you refer to the workbook as `wbf`, but you declared it as `wb`.

Comment: To echo what Mat said, *why* do you want to add this to the `ThisWorkbook` module? It would be much neater, more maintainable and more common to add a new module...

Comment: @Wolfie My code is doing something automatically in all the sheets when I click somewhere in one page. It works only when I implement it in 'ThisWorbook'.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am rather new in VBA. could you please give me some more hints? I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I receive this error in MATLAB: 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'

Comment: You could have a standard "on action" sub in the workbook/worksheet which calls another sub in a module. Then programmatically update the sub in the module, and keep all of the actual code there.

Comment: I found  a very good soltution here: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b823faa5-a432-4435-84cd-a04eadcbd1f5/loading-a-subroutine-into-thisworkbook-using-vba?forum=exceldev)